# Execute a Maven phase without the previous ones

Tags: java, maven

Can I execute a Maven phase (say: deploy) *without* implicitly calling the previous ones?

The reason: I would like to construct something like `install site-deploy (only-deploy)` to make sure that the deployment of the artifact only happens if all other phases/goals were successful. I cannot replace `(only-deploy)` with `deploy:deploy` because some projects which use this configuration have additional goals in the deploy phase.

Comment: Did you see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5591268/8513835) and broader discussion on how to manage phases in multiproject setup through profiles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147714/how-to-skip-install-phase-in-maven-build-if-i-already-have-this-version-installed) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude one of Maven's lifecycle phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877500/how-to-exclude-one-of-mavens-lifecycle-phase)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is called lifecycle for a reason. When we start with the next major release of Maven, we'll work on advanced lifecycle handling, where https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5666 is part of the solution for your issue.

Both the install and deploy plugin have an experimental xxxAtEnd, maven-site-plugin deploy goal should require such option as well.

Comment: Maven-site-plugin still has `skip` and `skipDeploy` parameters. Can they be utilized through configuring profiles to achieve finally the goal of not triggering deploy phase of mentioned 'projects with additional goals on deploy phase'?

Answer (score 1):

It's (now) [possible](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-goals-phases#maven-plugin):

> To run a specific goal without executing its entire phase (and the
> preceding phases), we can use the command:
>
> ```
> mvn <PLUGIN>:<GOAL>
> ```
>
> For example, to run the integration-test goal from the Failsafe
> plugin, we need to run:
>
> ```
> mvn failsafe:integration-test
> ```

another example: `mvn compiler:compile`

Comment: Running a plugin goal from command line was always possible, but does not solve the issue.

Comment: @JFabianMeier ah thx I see. I did not read carefully enough.