# Execute maven install phase without executing maven compile

Tags: maven, continuous-integration

Working with a multi-module project. Want to run maven commands as follows:

```
mvn clean compile
```

Then maven install phase without again executing maven compile

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

You would need to call the goals directly, phases cannot be run separately.

Comment: Please elaborate on how to separately run goals. Tried `mvn clean install -DskipTests` followed by test goal execution `mvn surefire:test`. But the goal fails, as its unable to find classes

Comment: I am not sure whether the tests are compiled if you skip tests. Generally, this is not the idea of Maven. The idea is to call `mvn clean install` and do _all_ the stuff in one run.

Comment: Does running
`mvn clean install -dskipTests`
followed by
`mvn test` the right approach? It will compile tests, but will code already compiled in the first step be skipped?

Comment: Probably. But the best approach would be to just call `mvn clean install` because it already runs the tests.

Answer (score 0):

you can (now) skip phases by directly calling the goal via

```
mvn <plugin>:<goal>
```

e.g.

```
mvn compiler:compile
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72315201/1915920) for details.

for [install](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) it should be `mvn install:install`